# Vuejs load component via v-if and use v-show afterwards

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I want to load a component for the first time via v-if condition but once its rendered I want to toggle its visiblity via v-show, is there any preferred way of achieving it?

Answer (score 1):

How about emitting an event from the component when it's first created / mounted and listening for that to toggle the `v-show`.

For example

```html
<my-component v-if="componentLoad" v-show="componentLoaded && componentToggle"
              @load="componentLoaded = true" />
```

```js
data: {
  componentLoad: false,
  componentLoaded: false,
  componentToggle: true,
}
```

and in the component

```js
mounted () {
  this.$emit('load')
}
```

Then you just need to flip `componentLoad` to initially create and mount the component and then alter `componentToggle` to show / hide it.